# how to make a join in the same table (By index)

Tags: postgresql

I have this Table

```
Player #1
Player #2 
Player #3 
Player #4 
Player #5 
Player #6
```

and I have to create another view of pairings like this :

```
Player #1 | Player #4
Player #2 | Player #5
Player #3 | Player #6
```

How to can make this view with Postgresql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` to join the table on to itself and pull out a list of every possible pair combination:

```sql
SELECT t1.player, t2.player
FROM table t1
CROSS JOIN table t2
```

To show each player playing only once you can combine two sub-queries of the first 3 and last 3 players together:

```sql
SELECT
  UNNEST( ARRAY(
    SELECT player FROM playertable ORDER BY player LIMIT 3
  ) ),
  UNNEST( ARRAY(
    SELECT player FROM playertable ORDER BY player OFFSET 3
  ) );
```

Comment: Thanks Gareth!, But how to i can limit this only a 1 match for player. This query return me all posible convinations for every player,  but i only need 
Player #1 | Player #4
Player #2 | Player #5
Player #3 | Player #6
Its possible do this only with postgresql? or i need do this with code?

Comment: @user3285408 I've added an additional query to my original answer to show each player playing only once.